The _tests folder format for externalising tests is not working for me
I tried to use the _tests folder format for externalising the tests for the yaml openApi spec but things don't seem to work for me. Whenever I run the rest, the command line shows have this file is not used. Any example corresponding to how will it work will be of great help. Thanks
Tried _data format but didn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hello Gagandeep, thanks for posting the question. CTO of Specmatic here. Relevant documentation link - https://specmatic.in/documentation/contract_tests.html#externalized-test-data. Can you please share more details, error message, etc. so that I can help you on this issue?

Hi @HariKrishnan need one more help. I have few yaml files which I use as tests . But I want to run few of them based on some parameter. I am not using junit. Can we do it. Please give a simple example
